# The library to expand TextView doesn't work while using Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, textview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using  "it.mike5v:viewmore-textview:1.1.3" library. When I first enter, it shows the Read more text, but when I go back (backbutton) and enter again the read more text is gone. I have the textview inside of Coordinator layout. I think that is the problem. I have tried a lot of other libraries but this one is the best one.
Here's some code

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:liftOnScroll="true"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:contentScrim="@color/black"
                app:statusBarScrim="@color/black"
                app:scrimAnimationDuration="300"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/masterclass_cover_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                    android:clipToOutline="false"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_background"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:src="@drawable/profile_background" />

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@null"
                                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_backbutton_with_arrow"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                      
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <it.mike5v.viewmoretextview.ViewMoreTextView
                    android:id="@+id/masterclass_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_light_color"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:ellipsizeText="@string/read_more"
                    app:ellipsizeTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:duration="100"
                    app:visibleLines="10" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my fragment

```
        binding.masterclassDescription.setOnClickListener {
            binding.masterclassDescription.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the library (and if you have issues with its functionality specifically, contact the author / add an issue to their repository's tracker) but it sounds like you want to store some "opened" state, even when the user backs out of the fragment?

Having the state reset is normal behaviour, you've left the screen so you're coming back in fresh - if you want to override that, you'll need to store the current state ([e.g. in `SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)) and read it when you're setting up the fragment. For example:

```
companion object {
    const val KEY_READ_MORE_EXPANDED = "read more expanded"
}

// keep a convenient reference to this, initialise it in one of the setup lifecycle callbacks
lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

// wherever you're doing your view setup
prefs = requireActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
// initialise the open state based on whatever state is stored
// I have no idea what the property you need to set is called, I just used 'expanded'
binding.masterclassDescription.expanded = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_READ_MORE_EXPANDED, false)

binding.masterclassDescription.setOnClickListener {
    binding.masterclassDescription.toggle()
    // store the state - again I don't know what the real property you need is called
    // You could also do this in onPause, or onStop, or onSaveInstanceState instead
    val isExpanded = binding.masterclassDescription.expanded
    with(prefs.edit()) {
        putBoolean(KEY_READ_MORE_EXPANDED, isExpanded)
        apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response firstly. No, I don't want to save the state. The library has the option if you want to let the text view expanded, but my problem is that the text view options to expand and collapse hide after I enter the second time in the fragment

Comment: @flutra oh you mean there's an expand/shrink control that's there the first time, but it doesn't show up the next time? (The `ellipsizeText` right.) From looking at the project page, if the extra text is hidden then it's in its collapsed stat, so the *View more* text should be there - it doesn't seem like a layout issue (it's possible, but if the view is "working" otherwise it seems like it's handling it). Opening a fresh Fragment should be the same every time, so this seems like a cached Fragment being reattached, and maybe it's not written to handle that properly

Comment: I don't know if the project's being supported, so all I can suggest is calling `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` on that view and see if giving it a kick fixes it - maybe do it in `onResume()` or something. If not, I'd try a different library, there are a lot of them! You could even write something yourself, depending on what you need - it's basically a `TextView` with its `layout_height` or `maxLines` being changed